# Magento 1 - Custom required formfield on checkout

Tags: validation, form-validation

I have added a custom textarea field on the shippingmethode section.
That field needs to be required. Is there any way to do this?

Basicly it has this content;
https://jsfiddle.net/bbsrsbbd/1/

```
<form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="">

  <textarea rows="6" name="shipping_arrival_comments" id="shipping_arrival_comments" placeholder="Comments here"></textarea>

  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>

</form>
```

When clicking on the button it has to validate/check if the textarea is empty or not.

Is there someone who can point me to the right direction?
Rather don't have it too advanced.
Adding just required="required" doesn't work unfortinately.

This works when I add this script but it goes to the next order section when I click on the button.

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save(); val();">

<script>
    function val()
    {
      if(document.getElementById("shipping_arrival_comments").value==null || document.getElementById("shipping_arrival_comments").value=="")
alert("blank text area")
    } 
</script>
```